# Font tag in Option tag for combobox not working

Tags: css, html

I am designing a dropdown combobox to show the price listing of products. 
For that I have embedded the Rupee font in css.

This is the code:

```
<select class="comboboxstyle" name="sports" id="sports">
  <option class="optionstyle" value="subscribe">Subscribe</option>
  <option class="optionstyle" value="monthly">Monthly <span style="font-family:Rupee">`</span>30</option>
  <option class="optionstyle" value="weekly" >Weekly<span style="font-family:Rupee">`</span>20</option>
  <option class="optionstyle" value="daily">Daily<span style="font-family:Rupee">`</span>10</option>
</select>
```

But, the browsers are not supporting the font tag in option tag, whereas it is working fine if it's not in the option tag.
I can't apply the Rupee font in the whole thing, as then only rupee symbol shows and other text disappears.

Any help...

Comment: Because your font-family is not supported in other computer, I guess

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a HTML tag inside `<option>`, your workaround is using the style for the `<option>` itself like this sample:

```
<select>
    <option style="font-weight: bold;">Text Text 1</option>
    <option style="font-family: Rupee;">Text Text 2</option>
    <option style="color: #FF0000;">Text Text 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a properly encoded (Unicode encoded) font, or find a replacement for the rupee symbol (a name, an abbreviation, an international currency code, another recognized symbol, or whatever suits the context and audience).

I suppose you mean INDIAN RUPEE SIGN (U+20B9) and not the older, more widely supported generic RUPEE SIGN. The new symbol has been implemented in several properly encoded fonts, see
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/fontsupport.htm
but note that the information applies to fairly new versions of the fonts – for example, modern Arial contains it, but old versions of Arial (created before the symbol was defined) obviously won’t.

But you might consider using a suitable free font, such as DejaVu Sans, as a downloadable font, via `@font-face`. This would mean that your `select` menus have a font different from the rest of the page, but this should not be a big problem. People are used to such things, and even by default, many browsers use a special font there.

The reason why setting the entire element’s font fails is that the Rupee font used is one of the 8-bit fonts around, trying to implement some new (or otherwise special) symbols in a quick and dirty way. The trick is based on an old idea (nowadays mostly abandoned, except in contexts like this) of changing the identity of a character by changing the font. That is, turning “a” to “b” by using a font where a glyph for “b” appears in place of “a”. Such tricks generally fire back, one way or another.